# C++ variant for Java long?

Tags: java, c++, long-integer, primitive-types

Is there a C++ variant for the `long` primitive data-type?
A C++ `long` is only 4 bytes, while a Java `long` is 8 bytes.

So: Is there a non-decimal primitive type with a size of 8 bytes in C++?
Maybe with some tricks?

Thanks

Comment: A `long` in C++ is not always 4 bytes (32 bits); in principle, the size of a `long` is system-dependent (it might be different sizes on different operating systems or compilers). In Java it's always 64 bits, regardless of the underlying platform.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft Visual C++ defines an `__int64` type that's equivalent to Java's `long`. gcc has `int64_t`. There's even a `long long int` type defined in the ISO C99 standard, however according to the standard it's *at least* 64 bits wide, but could be wider.

But apart from the size, there's also endianness to consider. The Java standard mandates big endian, but with C, endianness is AFAIK always platform-dependant.

Comment: What do you mean with "the Java standard mandates big endian"? Java primitive types are abstracted from the actual low-level storage of their content, so there's no way to tell which endianess is used by a specific Java VM.

Comment: @jarnbjo: Ok, to be completely exact: the java standard mandates that primitives behave as if they were big endian wherever it matters, such as inside class files, or when they're serialized.

Comment: The Java standard does not mandate big endianness. In Java you don't have direct access to memory (no pointers) so there is no need to mandate any endianness.

Comment: What you are saying is that Java class files and serialized objects are using a big endian format (which is correct). That has however nothing to do with how Java VMs are storing and managing primitive times internally at run time.

Comment: note that int64_t is defined by the standard to optionally reside in in cstdint or stdint.h, so it is not exactly gcc's invention

Answer (score 3):

C++ has a `long long` type, with a length of 64 bits (on most platforms).

Comment: Technically it doesn't, but most compilers support it (and C's `stdint.h` header, which defines `int64_t` and `uint64_t`) as an extension.

Comment: Standardized only in C++0x, not the current C++03.

Answer (score 2):

Since C++11, there are [fixed width integer types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) in the `<cstdint>` header.
In your scenario, you would want to use `std::int64_t` or `std::uint64_t`.

Because it is part of the C++11 language specification, platform and compiler compatibility should be guaranteed.